# What do dummy files become when used for measuring performance with the command dd if=/dev/zero?

Tags: command-line, dd

When doing a disk performance measurement using the `dd` command, such as in
`$ dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sdc count=10 bs=100M`, what do the transferred files become after being transferred to /dev/sdc ?
Is there a need to delete them manually ?

Comment: This doesn't "transfer a file" at all; it just writes zeros in place of whatever data was on the disk.  Any filesystem on the disk is ignored (and probably destroyed).  I hope you didn't have anything on that disk you wanted to keep.

Comment: I sometimes used a command like this to obliterate the partition table.